# Python sql search inside a loop returning the same value

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am currently having a few issues checking a database in python inside a loop.

Each time i am presented with the same value.

My goal is to check a table called seeTicketsEvents for empty event ids.

Then for each check another table called seeTicketsTickets for the name & data and then pass the id back to the first table.

when i query the second table with the function see_tickets_check_row(row) each time i get the same result.

`

```
def connect_to_db():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="root",
        database="db",
        unix_socket= "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock"
    )

    return mydb
```

`

`

```
def see_tickets_map_db():
    mydb = connect_to_db()
    with mydb.cursor() as mycursor:

        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `seeTicketsEvents` WHERE `ED_eventID` IS NULL")
        
        for row in mycursor:
            
            print(row)
            see_tickets_check_row(row)
            


def see_tickets_check_row(data_row):
    mydb = connect_to_db()
    with mydb.cursor() as mycursor:
        showdate = data_row[3]
        showname = data_row[4]

        print(showdate)
        print(showname)

        rowNew = []

        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `seeTicketsTickets` WHERE `showName` = showname AND `showDate` = showdate LIMIT 1")


        for rowNew in mycursor:
            #print(rowNew)
            return rowNew[2]
```

`

I have tried putting the connections inside a with satment and also tried closing the connection all with no luck.

Any help would be hugely appreacated.

Comment: I tried this:
        val = (
            data_row[4],
            data_row[3]
            )

        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `seeTicketsTickets` WHERE `showName` = '%s' AND `showDate` = '%s' LIMIT 1",val)

But get the error:

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BRISTOL COMEDY CABARET - SATURDAY 8:00PM SHOW (rotunda comedy club)'' AND `showD' at line 1

Comment: @StevenHelliwell: as per my answer, don't put quotes around the `%s` placeholders.

Comment: You don´t need 2 queries to to that, you can do it with just one query

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this line:

```py
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `seeTicketsTickets` WHERE `showName` = showname AND `showDate` = showdate LIMIT 1")
```

What does the query

```sql
SELECT * FROM `seeTicketsTickets` WHERE `showName` = showname AND `showDate` = showdate LIMIT 1
```

return?

It returns the first row from `seeTicketsTickets` where the value in the column `showName` equals the value in the column `showname` and the value in the column `showDate` equals the value in the column `showdate`.  Column names are not case-sensitive in MySQL, so you are comparing two columns against themselves, and a value in a column will always be equal to itself if it's not `NULL`. So you'll get the first row where the values in the `showName` and `showDate` columns are not `NULL`, where 'first' is whichever row the database happens to return first.

I suspect you want to pass the values of your local variables `showdate` and `showname` into your query. To do that, write the following:

```py
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `seeTicketsTickets` WHERE `showName` = %s AND `showDate` = %s LIMIT 1", (showname, showdate))
```